# VPS DNS Name Server Not Working

Tags: windows, server, dns, nameservers

I have a VPS server running Windows Server 2016 on 1&1 with a domain pointing to this server. I have created 2 subdomains ns1.worktechlabs.co.uk and ns2.worktechlabs.co.uk that point to the IP of this server.
I have another domain pointing to ns1 and ns2 on their name servers.
Also have configured the following DNS in Windows:

[DNS CONFIGURATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2lMj.png)

Any idea why it does not work?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you opened the firewall ports?

Comment: Yes, and also called 1&1 to ask about their firewall and everything is fine. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: I mean have you checked the windows firewall service on your server instance ? (rather than the providers)

Comment: Yes, Finally I solved the problem, After create the NS1 / NS2 DNS, I have to create a zone for the domain who is pointing to the server with the basics DNS A / AAAA / CNAME / MX.